Why are current, voltage and resistance all low in this scenario?

My understanding here is that compared to the internal resistance of the source, the resistance of a human is very low so terminal pd is also low. Then if current chooses the path of least resistance why is current in the circuit still low?

The two resistances are in series.

This question, and the "answer" it expects, is terrible. What idiot comes up with that stuff?!

The answer is Ohm's Law. First, let's bust a myth. Current does not take the path of least resistance; that's nonsense. It takes all paths available following parallel circuit laws.
So, I have an electric horse fence. It operates on about 8 kV and is guaranteed to teach you a nasty lesson if you or a horse touches it. However, it will not harm you unless you jump and hurt yourself by hitting something. The same principle is used for tasers and cattle prods. The source impedance is high, so it cannot deliver a lethal shock; it will teach you a lesson the hard way.
I learned my lesson the hard way as a kid on a farm. I pissed on the electric fence despite being warned. I never did it again. I forget the limit, I seem to recall a 5 mA maximum current. That would indicate the source impedance is roughly 8 kV / 5 mA = 1.6 MΩ. Add in the series human resistance of 100 to 100 kΩ, which is still limited to less than 5 mA.

Is 100 to 100 kohm supposed to be something else?

The human body's resistance range is 100 to 100 Kohms in series with 1.6 Mohm. The source impedance limits the current.
You need to find a credible source of information, PMT is making it up.

I was fishing for whether you meant 100 kohm to 100 kohm (a typo) or 100 ohm to 100 kohm (three orders of magnitude).

PMT Education has goofed up big time here. The cited nonsense from the textbook is extremely dangerous advice, for the following reasons:

Any voltage-regulated supply strives to have zero output impedance as long as the current limit is not exceeded. A decent 1kV, 1mA power supply has ≈0Ω output impedance as long as no more than 1mA flows out of the output. When 1mA is reached, the incremental impedance becomes approximately infinite, but the 1mA current still flows.

Supplies of any kind do not inherently need to have "high" output impedance. You could design one to have a very high output impedance, perhaps to protect hapless students in a lab, but that is counterproductive.
It would be rather dangerous to teach students that high voltage supplies are safe, whereas this would only happen in a student lab, and every other high voltage supply they'll find outside of the student lab will happily injure them or kill them.

Suppose we have a 1000V power supply. It needs to have 1MΩ output impedance to inherently limit the current to 1mA. That's not a safe current to flow through a human body. For lab environment where "hapless students" are present, medical limits - say 100μA maximum - would be more appropriate. For that, the supply would need 10MΩ output impedance. Whereas 1MΩ is already quite a bit of output impedance for any sort of a supply.

There is always parasitic capacitance within the output circuit of any power supply. That capacitance will discharge through the hapless student without any regard for what the output impedance of the power supply is. At the moment of discharge, the effective source impedance is approximately equal to the equivalent series resistance of the parasitic capacitance and/or any lumped capacitance added to the circuit.
A 0.2 Joule discharge energy limit is generally considered to produce no nuisance reflex reaction. Discharges above that energy, up to about 10J, will cause increased levels of reflex reaction that can cause serious injury due to falls, hitting stationary objects, etc. Above 10J, ventricular fibrillation may occur.
A 400nF capacitor charged to 1000V carries 0.2J of energy - just below the reflex reaction threshold. 400nF is much more than typical parasitic capacitances, but the unwitting students will surely find a way to charge some capacitor up from the "safe" supply.
400V is considered to be the human skin breakdown voltage. Below this voltage, skin resistance is in series with any applied external voltage source. Above 400V, the skin has broken down and has zero impedance for the purpose of the analysis.



That would be the case if your body were in parallel with the high internal resistance of the supply, which is not possible since the internal resistance is in series with the voltage supply, producing very little current.
In a given circuit with in series resistors, the percentage of the supply voltage across each one is equal to the ratio of that resistor over the equivalent resistance of the entire circuit (voltage divider). So the power dissipated on a tiny resistor compared to the others is minimal.
